# compute maximum f1 score using precision_recall_curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, classification, precision-recall

For a simple binary classification problem, I would like to find what threshold setting maximizes the f1 score, which is the harmonic mean of precision and recall. Is there any built-in in scikit learn that does this? Right now, I am simply calling

```py
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_test_predicted_probas)
```

And then, I can compute the f1 score using the information at each index in the triplet of arrays:

```
curr_f1 = compute_f1(precision[index], recall[index])
```

Is there a better way of doing this, or is this how the library was intended to be used? Thanks.

Comment: Note I am using an XGBoost classifier with binary logistic output if that changes anything

Answer (score 16):

After calculating the precision, recall and threshold scores you get NumPy arrays.
Just use the NumPy functions to find the threshold that maximizes the F1-Score:

```
f1_scores = 2*recall*precision/(recall+precision)
print('Best threshold: ', thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)])
print('Best F1-Score: ', np.max(f1_scores))
```

Comment: what if we care about the "weighted f1 score"? To account for unbalanced classes

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes `precision_recall_curve` picks a few thresholds that are too high for the data  so you end up with points where both `precision` and `recall` are zero. This can result in `nan`s when computing F1 scores. To ensure correct output, use `np.divide` to only divide where the denominator is nonzero:

```
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_test_predicted_probas)
numerator = 2 * recall * precision
denom = recall + precision
f1_scores = np.divide(numerator, denom, out=np.zeros_like(denom), where=(denom!=0))
max_f1 = np.max(f1_scores)
max_f1_thresh = thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)]
```

Comment: That's a nifty usage of the out argument -- for other people who were briefly confused like me, f1_scores will default to zero where denom is not zero.